# Algebra: logarithms word question

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Initially there are $2000$ bacteria in a given culture. The number of bacteria $N$ is tripling every hour so $N=2000 \cdot 3^t$, where $t$ is the measurable in hours.

a) How many bacteria are present after $4$ hours?

b) How long is it until there are $1000000$ bacteria?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. You are encouraged to learn MathJax or LaTeX for typsetting and also to show any efforts you've done on trying to solve the problem. Especially if it looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of a question because part a) can be solved directly by substituting the number of hours in $N=2000*3^t$ for $t$. As far as b) is concerned, we can do: 
$$10^6=2*10^3*3^t$$
So lets solve for $t$, $$\frac{1000}2=500=3^t$$
Thus taking log of both sides, $$\log{500}=t\log3$$
So $$\boxed{t=\frac{\log500}{\log3}=\log_{3}500}$$